# Cannot get Ajax result with resolve(arg) Javascript / Odoo

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

As mentioned in title, when I pass argument into resolve(args) I cannot catch the result from an Ajax request. I got instead the args I passed in resolve().

```
// kind of Ajax call in Odoo software
var d = new instance.web.Model('advanced.search')
.call('check_duplication', ['paul']).done(function (name) {
    // expected name 'example', but got 'my_var' instead...
    return name
});

d.resolve('my_var');
```

Could you tell me how to manage that?

Thank you very much.

PS : thx guys for all the answers. I'll try to be more specific.
I actually extend an object, with arguments received I use them to call a server side then waiting for the results. Once I got the result I want call super and pass new argument.

```
MyObject.extend({
init: function(parent, data){
    var d = instance.web.Model('advanced.search')
    .call('check_duplication', [data]).done(function (name) {
        // do stuff
        return name
    });
    var newData = d;
    this._super.apply(this, newData);
    // super is called before my request is done so the new data are not sent to super.
    }
});
```

So I want to call super only when request is done. If I cache this in a variable like, var self = this, it does not work if I call, self._super..., inside //do stuff part of the done callback. I got an error back telling me self._super... Is not a function, it behaves like the parent don't wait for me anyway.

That is why I tried to use resolve in order to bypass this problem.

Comment: Yes. So what's your question, what do you actually *want* to do?

Comment: Notice the the API you're calling is flawed, it should return a promise (without a `resolve` method) instead of a deferred.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing an ajax request, you must not be calling [`.resolve`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) at all. The ajax does this for you - when it finishes, it calls `resolve` with its result.

To *catch the result*, you just use it in the callback function that you pass to [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
var d = new instance.web.Model('advanced.search')
  .call('check_duplication', ['paul']);

d.done(function (name) {
    console.log(name); // here it is!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your remarks in the done callback, it looks like `my_var` is a variable so pass it as a variable not as a string literal

```
// kind of Ajax call in Odoo software
var d = new instance.web.Model('advanced.search')
    .call('check_duplication', ['paul']).done(function (name) {
    // expected name 'example', but got 'my_var' instead...
    return name
});

d.resolve(my_var);
```